# errors in hadoop 3.0.0-alpha1 compilation on kubuntu 12.04

Tags: maven, ubuntu, hadoop, 64-bit

I've had problems to compile the 3.0.0-alpha1 Hadoop version on kubuntu 12.04 (64 bits).

Apparently, this version requires a [HADOOP-8887 patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-8887) is applied.

After preparing the installation with all dependencies on a machine, 
according to BUILD.txt and apply the patch, the error that would correct by this patch, still remains, as shown in the log file.

All information is welcome to help resolve the issue.

command for compiling:

```
mvn clean package -Pdist -Dtar -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -DskipTests -fail-at-end -Pnative
```

log file tail:

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    [INFO] Reactor Summary:

    [INFO] 

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................ SUCCESS [0.601s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Build Tools ......................... SUCCESS [0.365s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM ......................... SUCCESS [0.584s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations ......................... SUCCESS [0.793s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies .......................... SUCCESS [0.100s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM .................... SUCCESS [1.017s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins ....................... SUCCESS [1.050s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop MiniKDC ............................. SUCCESS [0.407s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth ................................ SUCCESS [0.978s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples ....................... SUCCESS [0.697s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Common .............................. SUCCESS [23.360s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS ................................. SUCCESS [0.600s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop KMS ................................. SUCCESS [4.903s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project ...................... SUCCESS [0.024s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Client ......................... SUCCESS [11.244s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS ................................ SUCCESS [17.609s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Native Client .................. SUCCESS [2.746s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS .............................. SUCCESS [12.556s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS BookKeeper Journal ............. SUCCESS [0.564s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS-NFS ............................ SUCCESS [0.758s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Project ........................ SUCCESS [0.021s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN ................................ SUCCESS [0.021s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN API ............................ SUCCESS [3.985s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Common ......................... SUCCESS [3.795s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Server ......................... SUCCESS [0.056s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Server Common .................. SUCCESS [1.618s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN NodeManager .................... SUCCESS [4.077s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Web Proxy ...................... SUCCESS [0.401s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN ApplicationHistoryService ...... SUCCESS [0.847s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Timeline Service ............... SUCCESS [1.369s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN ResourceManager ................ SUCCESS [5.544s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Server Tests ................... SUCCESS [0.749s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Client ......................... SUCCESS [1.743s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN SharedCacheManager ............. SUCCESS [0.449s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Timeline Plugin Storage ........ SUCCESS [0.512s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Timeline Service HBase tests ... SUCCESS [1.503s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Applications ................... SUCCESS [0.017s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN DistributedShell ............... SUCCESS [0.500s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Unmanaged Am Launcher .......... SUCCESS [0.338s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Site ........................... SUCCESS [0.018s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Registry ....................... SUCCESS [0.844s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Project ........................ SUCCESS [8.001s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Client .................... SUCCESS [0.061s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Core ...................... SUCCESS [2.869s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Common .................... SUCCESS [1.362s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Shuffle ................... SUCCESS [0.390s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce App ....................... SUCCESS [1.791s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce HistoryServer ............. SUCCESS [0.848s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce JobClient ................. SUCCESS [2.293s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce HistoryServer Plugins ..... SUCCESS [0.214s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce NativeTask ................ FAILURE [9.687s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Examples .................. SUCCESS [0.666s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce ........................... FAILURE [0.515s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Streaming ................. SUCCESS [0.657s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Distributed Copy .................... SUCCESS [2.721s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Archives ............................ SUCCESS [0.972s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Archive Logs ........................ SUCCESS [0.393s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Rumen ............................... SUCCESS [0.554s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Gridmix ............................. SUCCESS [0.620s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Data Join ........................... SUCCESS [0.264s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Extras .............................. SUCCESS [0.304s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Pipes ............................... SUCCESS [2.345s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop OpenStack support ................... SUCCESS [0.336s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Amazon Web Services support ......... SUCCESS [0.645s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Azure support ....................... SUCCESS [0.622s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Client .............................. SUCCESS [3.436s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Mini-Cluster ........................ SUCCESS [0.432s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Scheduler Load Simulator ............ SUCCESS [1.044s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Azure Data Lake support ............. SUCCESS [0.674s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools Dist .......................... SUCCESS [4.542s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Kafka Library support ............... SUCCESS [0.188s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools ............................... SUCCESS [0.015s]

    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Distribution ........................ SUCCESS [18.374s]

    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE

    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    [INFO] Total time: 2:58.223s

    [INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 01 17:10:11 BRST 2016

    [INFO] Final Memory: 250M/629M

    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------



      [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-alpha1:cmake-compile (cmake-compile) on project hadoop-ma

        preduce-client-nativetask: make failed with error code 2 -> [Help 1]

        org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-alpha1:cm
        ake-compile (cmake-compile) on project hadoop-mapreduce-client-nativetask: make failed with error code 2
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)

      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)

      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)

      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)

      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)

      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)

      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)

      at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)

      at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)

      at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)

      at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)

      at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)

      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)

      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)

      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)

      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: make failed with error code 2

    at org.apache.hadoop.maven.plugin.cmakebuilder.CompileMojo.runMake(CompileMojo.java:229)

    at org.apache.hadoop.maven.plugin.cmakebuilder.CompileMojo.execute(CompileMojo.java:96)

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)

        ... 19 more

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (dist) on project hadoop-mapreduce: An Ant BuildE
xception has occured: exec returned: 1

[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="/home/hadoop/mnt/hadoop-3.0.0-alpha1-src/hadoop-mapreduce-project/target" ex
ecutable="bash">... @ 10:125 in /home/hadoop/mnt/hadoop-3.0.0-alpha1-src/hadoop-mapreduce-project/target/antrun/build-main.xml

[ERROR] -> [Help 1]

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (
dist) on project hadoop-mapreduce: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 1
around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="/home/hadoop/mnt/hadoop-3.0.0-alpha1-src/hadoop-mapreduce-project/target" executable
="bash">... @ 10:125 in /home/hadoop/mnt/hadoop-3.0.0-alpha1-src/hadoop-mapreduce-project/target/antrun/build-main.xml

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)

    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)

    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)

    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)

    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)

        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)

        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)

        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)

        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 1
around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="/home/hadoop/mnt/hadoop-3.0.0-alpha1-src/hadoop-mapreduce-project/target" executable
="bash">... @ 10:125 in /home/hadoop/mnt/hadoop-3.0.0-alpha1-src/hadoop-mapreduce-project/target/antrun/build-main.xml

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:355)

        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)

        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more

Caused by: /home/hadoop/mnt/hadoop-3.0.0-alpha1-src/hadoop-mapreduce-project/target/antrun/build-main.xml:10: exec returned: 1

    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:646)

        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)

        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)

        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)

        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)

        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)

        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)

        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)

        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)

        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)

        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:327)

        ... 21 more

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-mapreduce-client-nativetask
```